# Converting mm:ss to only seconds (java)

Tags: java, string, time, integer, seconds

Part of my current project is to convert mm:ss to seconds...but the user has the option to enter x:xx or xx:xx.

For example, if someone wanted to enter one minute and thirty seconds into the program, they have the option to write it as either "01:30" or "1:30". And the output of both would be 90 seconds.

This is my current code.

```
System.out.print("Time (mm:ss): ")

String time = scan.nextLine(); 
        int min = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, time.indexOf(':'))) * 60;
        int sec = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(3, time.length()));
        int duration = (min + sec);
    
        System.out.println("Seconds: " + duration)
```

It works whenever I enter xx:xx, but fails when I enter x:xx.

I am not sure how to only read the characters after ":" . If I start the substring at ":" (I have it at 3 now), it can't convert to int because it reads the ":".

I have looked all over Google and my textbook, but have not found anything. I assume I am just using the wrong technique. The code needs to stay within the parameters of basic beginner String methods. Thank you!

Comment: 1:30 is 90 seconds... also [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: So add one to the substring index?

Comment: Edited it to 90, thought I wrote 2:30.

Comment: How would I add one to the index? I've tried "+1" with no luck.

Comment: Easier to use the `split` method than  `substring` and `indexOf`.

Comment: I tried adding one outside of the parenthesis and it worked! Thanks!!!

Comment: We haven't been taught the "split" method yet, so even I'd be penalized if I used it.

Comment: error is because you are using 3 as index where it can be 2 in case of 1:30

Comment: I tried 2, didn't work for the case of 01:30.  But adding "+1" after time.indexOf(':') worked like a charm! Now I have to figure out how to mark the question as answered lol.

Comment: @HunterB After a quarantine period, I think 12 hours, you may select your own answer as accepted. Then it will be clear to everyone that the question is answered.

Answer (score 3):

This answer probably does not stay within the parameters of basic beginner `String` methods as requested. I think it will be useful for other readers of your question who don’t have the same limitation.

### java.time.Duration

The `Duration` class is the class to use for an amount of time like 1 minute 30 seconds. Unfortunately, the `Duration` class can only parse strings in ISO 8601 format (link below), but the string conversion isn’t hard with a regular expression. And fortunately in ISO 8601 format leading zeroes don’t matter. The `Duration` class is part of java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

ISO 8601 format for a duration is like `PT01M30S`. Think of it as a period of time of 01 minute 30 seconds. If the format feels unusual at first, it is straightforward. So let’s convert to it. The following method accepts your user’s format, converts and returns a `Duration`.

```
public static Duration parseDuration(String durStr) {
    String isoString = durStr.replaceFirst("^(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{2})$", "PT$1M$2S");
    return Duration.parse(isoString);
}
```

`Duration` has a `toSeconds` method for converting to seconds. So let’s try the whole thing out:

```
    System.out.println(parseDuration("01:30").toSeconds());
    System.out.println(parseDuration("1:30").toSeconds());
```

Output is the expected:

> ```
> 90
> 90
> ```

Consider whether you need to convert to seconds at all, though. Keeping the `Duration` objects as they are will probably make your code more self-explanatory.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

```
int sec = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(time.indexOf(':') + 1), time.length()));
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Here I have simplified your code.

```
String time = "1:30";
String[] timeUnit = time.split(":");
int totalSeconds = 60 * Integer.parseInt(timeUnit[0]) + Integer.parseInt(timeUnit[1]);
System.out.println("Seconds "+totalSeconds);
```